Merge column does not work using multicolumn
I use this code, but merging the column does not work exactly in the 4th row.
\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \caption{An overview of source of uncertainties, uncertainty propagation, and optimization algorithm}
    \label{tab:my_label}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XXX}
    \hline
     \multirow{2}{*}{Source of uncertainty} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Parameters} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Disturbances} \\
      & \cite{paulson2014fast,purnawan2024model,paulson2015stability} & \cite{yang2020robust,purnawan2022disturbance} \\ 
      \multirow{2}{*}{Uncertainty propagation} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{PCE} \\
      & \multicolumn{2}{X}{\cite{paulson2014fast,purnawan2024model,paulson2015stability}} \\ \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}



Have a look at the tabularray package. It makes merging cells very easy.

Hi! You should provide a full MWE (minimal working example) with the \documentclass, the \begin{document}, etc.

Welcome to TeX.SE! You prescribe multicolumn width with X. It should have width of two columns.

As I understand your question, you are after something like this:

As I mentioned in comment, you need to prescribe width of multicolumn cell such that span two columns. IN MWE below I add vertical lines that width of last two columns are better visible:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\caption{An overview of source of uncertainties, uncertainty propagation, and optimization algorithm}
\label{tab:my_label}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X|X|X|}
    \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Source of uncertainty} 
    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Parameters} 
        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Disturbances} \\
    & \cite{paulson2014fast,purnawan2024model,paulson2015stability} 
        & \cite{yang2020robust,purnawan2022disturbance} \\ 
\multirow{2}{*}{Uncertainty propagation} 
    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{PCE}       \\
        & \multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep}X|}%{\cite{paulson2014fast, purnawan2024model, paulson2015stability}}      
        {some longer text in two lines which span two table columns ...}
        \\ \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}

Nex time please instead of code fragment ptovide complete small documnet called MWE (Minimal Working Example) which reproduce xour problers (somthing similar as I do above).
Addendum:
By use of tabularray package, MWE is:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}


\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\caption{An overview of source of uncertainties, uncertainty propagation, and optimization algorithm}
\label{tab:my_label}
    \begin{tblr}{colspec = {l X X },
                 cell{1,3}{1} = {r=2}{},
                 cell{1}{2,3} = {c},
                 cell{Y,Z}{2} = {c=2}{c},
                 hspan = minimal,
                 hlines, vlines % just to show columns width
                 }
Source of uncertainty
    &   Parameters 
            &   Disturbances    \\
    & \cite{paulson2014fast,purnawan2024model,paulson2015stability} 
            & \cite{yang2020robust,purnawan2022disturbance} \\ 
Uncertainty propagation  
    &   PCE &                   \\
    &   some longer text in two lines which span two table columns ...
            &   \\ 
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}

which gives:


Thank you, I tried your code, and it works perfectly.
